# Getting transaction details using PayPal REST API (v2) not working

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, php-curl

I want to get the full details of a PayPal transaction by its ID using the PayPal REST API.

I tried to do it as the following:

```php
<?php
include("config.php");

// Reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/
$ch = curl_init("https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Accept-Language: en_US"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $restapp['client_id'] . ':' . $restapp['secret']);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$access_token = json_decode($result, true)['access_token'];

// Reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/get-transaction/#on-the-server
$ch = curl_init("https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/<transaction_id>");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

But this always returns error `INVALID_RESOURCE_ID`. Please note that I am using the client ID and client secret of my **live** application, and the transaction ID that I use is a **live** transaction ID too.

After doing some searches, I've found that `https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/orders/<transaction_id>` works instead of `https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/<transaction_id>` .. but v1 doesn't return as much information as v2

What am I doing wrong on the v2 endpoint?

Kind regards.

Comment: What value are you passing in for transaction_id?  I think you need to use an order_id instead.

Comment: @DrewAngell - What is an order ID?

Comment: When working with the v2 API you'll be using CreateOrder, and you would get an Order ID back in this response.